# orangehrm test email not send

Tags: email, testing, send, orangehrm

I have installed OrangeHrm 3.3.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 Server and now trying to configure SMTP Email.

The credentials and settings are correct. I am using same in SuiteCRM installed on CentOS 7.

The message I get

Settings Saved. Test email not sent.

I remember doing this on CentOS:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=on 
setsebool httpd_can_sendmail=on 
setsebool httpd_unified=on
```

Is there some similar settings for Apache on Ubuntu where I can allow sendmail on the server?

I would highly appreciate your input.

Thanks in advance.

/AAN